# iOS Swift: Value of type 'NotificationCenter' has no member 'publisher'

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm trying to use the new **Combine** framework with the **Notification Center** as Apple explained in this video:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/721/

You can find it in the slide 21.

It seems that my project does not read the Combine framework apis.

```
import Combine
import Foundation

let trickNamePublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .newTrickDownloaded)
```

And i'm getting this error:

**Value of type 'NotificationCenter' has no member 'publisher'**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently seems that in Xcode 11 beta there is this know issue:

> **The Foundation integration for the Combine framework is unavailable.**
>   The following Foundation and Grand Central Dispatch integrations with
>   Combine are unavailable: KeyValueObserving, NotificationCenter,
>   RunLoop, OperationQueue, Timer, URLSession, DispatchQueue,
>   JSONEncoder, JSONDecoder, PropertyListEncoder, PropertyListDecoder,
>   and the @Published property wrapper. (51241500)

link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_release_notes/

Indeed they weren't using Xcode during that presentation, but just code on slides

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed with **Xcode 11 beta 2**. From [Xcode 11 Beta 2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_2_release_notes):

> **The Foundation integration for the Combine framework is now available.**
>   The following Foundation and Grand Central Dispatch integrations with
>   Combine are available: KeyValueObserving, NotificationCenter, RunLoop,
>   OperationQueue, Timer, URLSession, DispatchQueue, JSONEncoder,
>   JSONDecoder, PropertyListEncoder, PropertyListDecoder, and the
>   @Published property wrapper. (51241500)

Comment: @Miotz I'm not sure, it's not mentioned in release notes so probably not.